# jquery slider max value

Tags: jquery, slider

i am using jquery slider plugin below this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#slider").slider({ min:-10 }, { max: 500 }, { step: 1 });
         $('#slider').bind('slidechange', function(event, ui) {
         var value = $('#slider').slider('option','value');
             alert(value);
         });
     });
</script>
```

But max value is not initialized,always set 100.Whats wrong?
thx

Answer (score 4):

You have to write it this way :

```
$("#slider").slider({ min:-10, max: 500, step: 1 });
```